If ancient Venus really were once habitable, what was its atmospheric composition and average surface temperature?

Some sources claim that billions of years ago, Venus may have had much cooler temperatures, enough for liquid water on it’s surface and these clouds on the day-side of Venus would raise Venus’ albedo and further protect Venus from runaway greenhouse. Apparently, this then changed as the sun grew too hot for even this to shield Venus. Others have suggested a LIP event caused Venus’ runaway greenhouse state.
Other sources claim Venus was never habitable because it was too hot to begin with.
Let’s assume Venus was habitable in the past (somehow). What would Venus’ atmosphere and average surface temperature be before it became uninhabitable?
I am planning to use this in a worldbuilding project which involves a planet very similar to habitable ancient Venus.

what has this to do with worlduilding? it's plain planetary history

@L.Dutch I need to know what ancient Venus (if it were habitable) was like so I can create a similar planet with a similar history. Also, the real history itself is up for debate and the current research tends to lean towards Venus never being habitable. So already a once-habitable Venus is a stretch.

Do you mean habitable by any life, or habitable to humans?  Earth is only habitable for most of the organisms that exist today because this is how early single celled organisms terraformed the planet.  If earlly Venus got the right set of chemotrophic life forms early on like we did, it could still have plenty of life on it today.

This seems to be speculative and TBD by the author of the  story as science's jury is still out (if there were one). We don't know, so any answer would be purely opinion-based.

@Nosajimiki Not necessarily habitable for humans no. Just temperatures sufficient for oceans covering the surface and a thinner atmosphere than modern Venus - like what the picture shows. My assumption is that it was somewhat like Earth during the Archaen Eon but I am not sure if the atmosphere of ancient Venus was primarily CO2 or primarily N2 (and if it still had more pressure than Earth’s atmosphere). Also, what was its average surface temperature in the middle of this period? If it was still hotter than Earth, how hotter?

??? Wikipedia says: Billions of years ago, Venus's atmosphere could have been much more like the one surrounding the early Earth, and that there may have been substantial quantities of liquid water on the surface. After a period of 600 million to several billion years, solar forcing from rising luminosity of the Sun and possibly large volcanic resurfacing caused the evaporation of the original water and the current atmosphere. With links to references to read.

"I am not sure if the atmosphere of ancient Venus was primarily CO2 or primarily N2 (and if it still had more pressure than Earth’s atmosphere)." Nobody knows. This does not seem relevant to worldbuilding, since you can simply decide what you want: copying a possible past state of Venus will not actually help your story.

@Escapeddentalpatient. This is where the difference between an informed guess and an uninformed guess becomes important.  In cases where the scientific community is divided, the most helpful way to answer a question like this is to identify WHY that division exists so that the OP can make informed decisions about the state of his planet when picking one model or another.  If he just picks one randomly, and does not know why that model exists, then he could accidentally add details to his setting that could only result in another model.

I agree, why your answer is valuable. @Nosajimiki best guess sounds fine to me.

Surface Temperature
If you just want to know the average temperature of an Earth like world at a Venus like distance, it is ~156°F.  You can use https://astro.sitehost.iu.edu/ala/PlanetTemp/index.html if you want to fiddle with exact atmospheric densities, albedos, etc.
There are plenty of extremophiles here on Earth that can survive those temperatures; so, it would have likely be survivable for microbial life at the very least.  Macroscopic life on Earth can generally not survive more than about ~140°F, but that is because most microbial organisms have proteins go through shape changes between about ~110-140°F.  So, as long as your DNA designs proteins around the higher temperatures, there is no reason to assume that macrobial life could not evolve at these temperatures too.
The biggest threat to life on your planet is not how hot Venus averages, but how much it could swing if the atmosphere were thinner.  Presently,  Venus's thick atmosphere and fast winds result in pretty close temperature between day and night despite days being 117 times as long as on Earth, if the atmosphere were thinner,  days could easily get hundreds of degrees hotter than nights.
Gas Composition
As for gas composition... it depends.  Most of the models we use for guessing at the early composition of planets assume that planets within a solar system all start off with similar ratios of everything, but evolve differently from there based on factors such as solar luminosity which can determine what substances become solid/liquid/gas, solar winds which can blow away the atmosphere (especially the lighter gases), magnetic fields and gravity which can help resist solar winds, volcanic activity which helps release gases that are otherwise buried, etc.
The younger a planet is, the less time these forces have to bring out a world's unique characteristics; so, earlly on Venus, Earth, and Mars are assumed to have been far more similar to each other than they are today.  So, while we do not have enough geological research on Venus to say definitively what it was like, accretion theory will get you close... baring the possible evolution of early lifeforms.
The big unknown about Venus's history is what kind of life may have at one point lived there.  Here on Earth it only took photosynthesizers about 200 million years to turn the Earth into a CO2 scarce, Nitrogen/Oxygen rich environment because they like to suck the CO2 and H2O out of the environment to form hydrocarbons and then releases the extra O2 into the air.  If your planet evolves photosynthetic carbon based lifeforms early enough, then it could have a similar atmosphere composition to modern day Earth.  Baring the existence of life, the composition should be similar to primordial Earth
But then again, you could evolve early life that works by different biological mechanisms than Earth life which could change the atmospheric composition in all sorts of ways.  For example, silicon based life might need to consume quartz to "breath" giving you an extra thick atmosphere rich in both CO2 and Oxygen,
The Hydrosphere
This is the big point of debate because Venus spins so slowly. If you give your planet really long days like Venus has, then things get harder to predict, but if you give your planet shorter Earth like days, then your earlly planet should be hot, but otherwise more like Earth than Venus.
The people who don't predict oceans on Venus assume that the oceans would boil away on the sun side of the planet... but this is actually a silly concern when you think about it.  Water vapor is a denser gas than most of the gases the make up Venus's atmosphere; so, even if it boils, and some escapes, it will not escape the planet any faster than the other gases that have accumulated on the planet over time; so, the only possibility is for the water to form clouds until it reached the dark side of the planet where the lower greenhouse effect would allow the dark side to drop to arctic temperatures. Here it would all precipitate and freeze.  The twilite area and the poles will almost certainly have liquid surface water while the night zones may only have liquid water under a deep layer of ice, and the day zone could have temperate liquid water under its boiling surface.
The other big difference is that the oceans will be more acidic than Earth because all that water, CO2, and heat will lead to a lot of Carbonic Acid... but again, early life could have a lot to say about this.  If your planet evolves Carbonic Acid consuming chemotrophs like Earth evolved methanotrophic chemotrophs, then it's possible that your planet will never acidify like Venus did.

And the winner in the category of “Best Answer to a Closed Question” goes to…! (Seriously good answer.)

@SRM And for our next award in the category of "Why Was This Question Even Closed?" this nominee asked about planetary formation on a literal World Building SE and got closed for being off topic...

Yup, this was pretty much the answer I was looking for.
Also, in terms of the sources saying Venus could’ve never had oceans, it’s because they say that when Venus formed, it formed initially in a Hadean hothouse state like Earth, but could not have cooled enough because the water vapour would condense into clouds on the nightside of the planet and not the dayside.

@Nosajimiki I have asked on Meta to discuss this question: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/why-close-hypothetical-question-about-possible-history-of-venus
